# A very simple example of the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let's consider functions defined on the interval $[1, \infty)$. Let $f_n(x) = 1/n^2$ for $1 \le x \le n^2 $, and $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x > n^2$. Clearly $f_n$ converges to the constant function $0$ pointwise (actually uniformly). Moreover, for each $n$, $f_n$ is dominated by $g(x) = 1/x^2$ which is integrable. So, by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, the integral sign and the limit on $n$ should be interchangable. But
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^\infty f_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^2 - 1}{n^2} = 1 \ne 0 = \int_1^\infty \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n.
$$
I think I must have made some silly mistakes or have some misconceptions. What is wrong?

Comment: You have $f_n (x) \leq 1/x $, not $f_n (x) \leq 1/x^2$.

Comment: Oops! Really silly mistake. PhoemueX, please make your comment as an answer if you want. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of $f_n (x)=1/n^2$ for $1\leq x \leq n^2$, we only have $f_n (x) \leq 1/x$ (with equality at $x=n^2$) and not $f_n (x)\leq 1/x^2$.